# pandas Timedelta doesn't recognize month intervals as string (`3M` or `P3M`)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I want to convert a string (`3M`, `3d`, etc.) to timedelta in pandas.
The function to do this is `pandas.Timedelta`. It works fine with:

```
>>> pandas.__version__
'1.1.5'
>>> pandas.Timedelta('1d')
Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
>>> pandas.Timedelta('3w')
Timedelta('21 days 00:00:00')
>>> pandas.Timedelta('2h')
Timedelta('0 days 02:00:00')
```

However, when I try to put interval in months, it doesn't do what I expect:

```
>>> pandas.Timedelta('2M')
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:00')
>>> pandas.Timedelta('P2M')
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')
```

The `P` infront is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and is referenced in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html).

I expect that these calls return the time delta in months. Why is this not working as I think I should expect? What is the proper way to get time difference using month strings?

P.S. I can use `pandas.Timedelta('60D')`, but that's not the point.

Comment: So, how many days should your "month" have? 28? 31? Note that a month is simply an ambiguous duration.

Comment: If you do pd.Timedelta('1Y') you get a useful warning: `FutureWarning: Units 'M', 'Y' and 'y' do not represent unambiguous timedelta values and will be removed in a future version` Because it's ambiguous you should define it how you desire using days